# Basic redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to have a redirect using `mod_rewrite`.

When someone opens http://aswt.mobileworldindia.com
then they will be automatically redirected to http://www.mobileworldindia.com/panels/mobile/index.php?subdomain=aswt

Please note that http://aswt.mobileworldindia.com is not an actual subdomain and doesn't exist at all and neither I want to have it. I just want to have a redirect in my site.

Tried following code but didnt work, can anybody tell me where I am wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.sellingsellingsold\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%1 [L,R=301]
```

This is uploaded at sellingsellingsold's root and I am trying to open http://aswt.sellingsellingsold.co.uk.
Please help me in getting it sorted. It has been 2 weeks since I am trying to achieve the redirection.

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with `php`. Rewriting is done by a module loaded inside the http server. I suggest you read the excellent manual. Then have a try, if you do not succeed post your attempts here. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I want to point out that re-writing is different from redirecting. Re-writes simply serve a different URL to the one displayed, and redirect will take you to a different URL entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this inside the main server configuration or inside a `.htaccess` file. Using the server configuration is preferred and more reliable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(aswt)\.mobileworldindia\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /panels/mobile/index.php?subdomain=%1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want to redirect from any possible subdomain instead of just "aswt." use (.+) instead of (aswt).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it more preferred to use the server config? I'd never heard that before. Surely it's less reliable since .htaccess overwrites it.

Comment: .htaccess files can only overwrite it if it is explicitly allowed (enabled) in the central server configuration. That is where the behaviour is controlled. Apart from that the syntax is slightly different (easier in some cases) and less confusing, since you have the rewrite rules in one place instead of having them spread over different files you have to consider. .htaccess files ofter get deleted by accident or forgotten when changing things. And the most important thing: you can use rewrite logging only from within the central server configuration.

Comment: @arkascha - This is not working my friend. I have tested it. Can you give me updated modrewrite code where aswt is hardcoded and remain fixed

Comment: Sorry, obviously I did not test that code in detail, I wrote it from experience. There might be some glitch in there, though I fail to see the problem right now. I suggest you turn on rewrite logging as I suggested. Set the log level to maybe 7 and monitor the logfile you configured whilst making a single request. The module will tell you in detail what is going on inside the rewrite engine. This really helps to pin down problems with rewriting.

Comment: @arkascha - When you say inside the server configuration file, where exactly is it?

Comment: can you help me how to enable rewrite log

Comment: Right _before_ where things like `DocumentRoot` and `Options` are defined, so most likely inside the main configuration of your virtual host. Oh: and when you make changes to the main server configuration you have to restart the server process for those changes to be read in again. Something like `/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful` or the like.

Comment: About rewrite logging: I suggest you take a look at the excellent manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html   It explains the two options you need in detail: `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`. All you have to do is specify a logfile where to write to and a log level (I suggest "7"). Then watch that file using something like `tail -f /path/to/logile` whilst making a single request from the browser.